# With JavaScript, how can I create divs that contain a group of elements created from a loop?

Tags: javascript

Right now I am using a for loop to go through 30 elements(sender,subject,body) and it is creating 30 separate divs, however I want to create 10 divs that each contain one of these elements.

```
for(var i = 0; i < window.geemails.length; i++ ) {


            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
            h1.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].subject;
            div.appendChild(h1);
            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);


            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
            h1.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].sender;
            div.appendChild(h1);
            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);


            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].body;
            div.appendChild(p);
            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);


         }
```

Comment: Well, just remove the repeat creations of divs. Essentially just delete the second and third `var div = document.createElement("div");` and the first and second `document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want each email to be in a separate `<div>` tag, then all you need to do is *not* create the extra HTML elements for each part of the email and instead using a single `<div>` where everything would be appended once. Here is your code modified - I've added CSS to outline the separate `<div>`s.

```js
window.geemails = [
  {
    subject: "Hello",
    sender: "Nigerian Prince",
    body: "You've won 1 MILLION dollars!"
  },
  {
    subject: "RE: RE: RE: RE: funny joke",
    sender: "Mom",
    body: "lol :D"
  },
  {
    subject: "Wrong &gt;",
    sender: "me",
    body: "disregard"
  }
]

for(var i = 0; i < window.geemails.length; i++ ) {
  //create only one div for the email content
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  //add subject
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].subject;
  div.appendChild(h1);

  //add sender
  h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].sender;
  div.appendChild(h1);

  //add body
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].body;
  div.appendChild(p);
  
  //add the whole email only once
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#main div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

With that said, I've got two suggestions for improving your code:

1. Use more meaningful names for variables, so instead of calling it `h1` just call it `subject` - it doesn't *matter* what the HTML element is. If you decide to store the subject in an `<h2>` you won't really feel the need to rename the variable.
2. Do not use `.innerHTML` if you can avoid it. Using `.textContent` is much safer. As a basic illustration you can see the email with title `Wrong &gt;` is actually rendered as `Wrong >` because it's interpreted as HTML. Here is the code improved slightly

```js
window.geemails = [
  {
    subject: "Hello",
    sender: "Nigerian Prince",
    body: "You've won 1 MILLION dollars"
  },
  {
    subject: "RE: RE: RE: RE: funny joke",
    sender: "Mom",
    body: "lol :D"
  },
  {
    subject: "Wrong &gt;",
    sender: "me",
    body: "disregard"
  }
]

for(var i = 0; i < window.geemails.length; i++ ) {
  var emailHolder = document.createElement("div");
  var emailData = window.geemails[i]; // you can get it only once instead of three times
  
  var subject = document.createElement("h1");
  subject.textContent = emailData.subject;
  emailHolder.appendChild(subject);

  var sender = document.createElement("h1");
  sender.textContent = emailData.sender;
  emailHolder.appendChild(sender);

  var body = document.createElement("p");
  body.textContent = emailData.body;
  emailHolder.appendChild(body);
 
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(emailHolder);
}
```

```css
#main div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much, this is a huge help!